# Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 - In what file are the keyboard shortcuts saved?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

In what file are the keyboard shortcuts saved in Linux Mint Cinnamon 18 ?

I want to backup the shortcuts so if I know the file where the shortcuts are saved, I can simply create a symlink to the shortcut file after reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Since the answer is obviously useful the question can not be that useless. Anyway, it helped me.

Comment: it is worth noting that (in Debian 11) the entire config is stored in `~/.config/dconf/user`, so if all you care about is backing up your settings you can just copy that binary file instead of running `dconf dump`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can utilize the following to export your keyboard shortcuts to a file:

```
$ dconf dump /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/ > dconf-settings.conf
```

This requires the `dconf-cli` package to be installed. Then, to import the file after making any desired keybinding changes:

```
$ dconf load /org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/ < dconf-settings.conf
```

Comment: Thanks, but thats does not answer my question unfortunately . The reason why i ask is, that i want to backup the shortcuts so i can simply create a symlink to the shortcut file after reinstalling the OS.

Comment: Apologies, I've updated my answer to include details for exporting the file. I've only been able to test this on Cinnamon 17, so let me know if you encounter any errors.

Comment: The dump works on Lubuntu(18.04) + Cinnamon (3.6.7).

Comment: On Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, this does not dump any key assignments. ;(

Comment: To clarify: On Linux Mint 20 Cinnamon, this outputs any overrides, but does not list the default assignments. I was hoping to have a list of _all_ key assignments so I could search it. The GUI does not support searching.

Comment: works on Debian 11 as well

Answer (score 0):

There are several **binary** files. Check the `dconf-overview.xml`, in the docs directory, inside this [zipped file](https://download.gnome.org/sources/dconf/0.30/dconf-0.30.1.tar.xz).