# Where are the Linux Mint xfce keyboard shortcuts saved?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, dconf

I am currently running "Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia" with the Desktop Environment "**xfce4**".
Because I have to setup several PCs, I want to write a bash script, that configures the keyboard shortcuts for the system.

I did some research, but none of these articles were what I was searching for. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422111/linux-mint-cinnamon-18-in-what-file-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-saved) for example the author is using *Cinnamon* as DE, so the given filepath (`/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/`) does not exist on my system.
In [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=159521) article the author is using the program `dconf-cli`. But i don't want to use an external application. I really want to know, where on my system, these shortcuts will be saved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml`

Replace `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` with `~/.config` if you don't have it as an environment variable.

You'll find the user configuration files for most XFCE4 applications in that `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/xfce4` folder, so you might want to simply copy that over for your DE configuration to be consistent between devices.

As an aside, the mentioned path `/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/` isn't meant to be an actual file on your filesystem.
It's a path stored in the [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf) database, which you can find at `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/dconf/user`
It's unfortunately not plaintext, and as such not very easy to manipulate without using the `dconf` command

Comment: While the environment variable `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` does not exist in my case, the file path `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` did contain the keyboard shortcuts I was searching for, thank you for the help!