# Keyboard shortcut to open a file on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, ubuntu-mate

Is there a way to create custom keyboard shortcut to open a file on Linux mint 20 (cinnamon)? I think Ubuntu mate 20.04 will have similar solution. Let's say I want open a file using `vim`. I tried adding custom shortcut with command `vim /path/to/file` and `xdg-open /path/to/file`, none of them worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422111/linux-mint-cinnamon-18-in-what-file-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-saved

Comment: @SHW Please elaborate how I can utilize that.