# How to programmaticaly add a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon

I am using **Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon**.

I am aware of the GUI way of adding a keyboard shortcut. Just open the "Keyboard" application and click the "Shortcuts" tab etc. Easy peasy.

But I am trying to create a "quick setup" script that I can run to configure the DE the way I like it. I don't understand how I can programmatically add a keyboard shortcut?

Let's say I have this executable: `~/.bin/foobar`. How can I configure `CTRL`+`ALT`+`t` to execute it, without using the GUI?

Comment: It's not as easy as cinnamon uses binary files: [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422111) - you can try the dump & load apporach (I have not tested it). Other DEs like XFCE use XML-type config files. Generally keyboard shortcuts and where to find them is quite a mess IMHO.

Comment: That's a shame. But thanks for the info.