# How to modify keyboard shortcut programmatically in linux mint cinnamon?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, dconf, gsettings

I want to create a bash script that automatically modify the keyboard shortcut in linux mint. Currently, I use Linux Mint 21.1, Cinnamon 5.6.8.

I want the script also affect the **keyboard settings** GUI here whenever I create a new shortcut:
[image: keyboard shortcut]

I have tried this script:

```bash
name="Flameshot Capture Screen"
schema="org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.custom-keybinding"
path="/org/cinnamon/desktop/keybindings/custom-keybindings/custom0/"
shortcut="['<Primary><Shift>Print']"
command="flatpak run org.flameshot.Flameshot gui"

# Check if flameshot is installed, otherwise install it
if ! flatpak list | grep -q org.flameshot.Flameshot; then
    flatpak install flathub org.flameshot.Flameshot
fi
# set values
gsettings set $schema:$path name "$name" 
gsettings set $schema:$path binding "$shortcut"
gsettings set $schema:$path command "$command"
```

for changing dconf, It was working. The changes are shown on **dconf editor**.
But in **keyboard settings** doesn't show up.
***It works only if i previously add custom shortcut in gui.***

I have tried several ways such as:

- using dconf dump
- restarting cinnamon and even the computer
  But not working.

I've seen this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422111/linux-mint-cinnamon-18-in-what-file-are-the-keyboard-shortcuts-saved), and it's relevant to a certain degree

Please help.